# SQL RawQuery tells me the column doesnt exist

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Could someone please tell me whats wrong with my SQLite Query? Its allways telling me the column 'plugins._id' wouldn't exist, but I'm sure it does. I'm reading it just two lines above this query.

```
return mDatenbank.rawQuery("SELECT plugins._id, plugins.name, plugins.number, 
plugins.device_id, connections.plugin1, connections.plugin2, addedDevices._id,
addedDevices.name, connections._id FROM connections INNER JOIN (plugins INNER JOIN
addedDevices ON plugins.device_id = addedDevices._id) ON connections.plugin2 =
plugins.device_id OR connections.plugin1 = plugins.device_id WHERE connections.plugin1=?
OR connections.plugin2=?;", new String[] {PlugInName, PlugInName});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not solve your problem, but the query must not be terminated with `;`. See what happens. [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.CancellationSignal%29)